# Flutter app variables reset each time you leave the page

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm making a flutter app. Each time I leave the page, the variables reset. How do I make it so that the data stays the same, even if you leave the page? I'm using getx for state management. Here is my code:

```
  //Button that leaves the page
  Align(
   alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    child: IconButton(
     onPressed: () => Get.back(),
       icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    ),
 ),
```

When you click the button, it leaves the page and resets the variable maintasks shown here.

```
      Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
            child: Text(
              maintasks,
              style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 23,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
              ),
            ),
          ),
       ),
```

There is a function which changes the variable maintasks to the user input. However this user input is reset each time you leave the page. I've tried using SetState to save the variable but for some reason it doesn't work.

Sorry if my question is worded badly. If anyone knows how to do this, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Widget state is reset as soon as the widget is disposed.
For this, using GetX, you could use GetXControllers
Example, let's imagine you need a state that's composed by a username and a password,

```dart
    class LoginController extends GetxController {//GetxController comes from Getx package
      var username = ''.obs;//creates a stream that can be listened from the UI, whose value is a String
      var password = ''.obs;//same here
      void onUsernameChanged(String newValue) {
        username(newValue);//changes username stream last value to newValue's
      }
      void onPasswordChanged(String newValue) {
        password(newValue);//the same
      }
    }
```

Now, you must insert an instance of this controller in your widget tree before the widget is built (For example, in initState)

```dart
    @override
      void initState() {
        _controller = Get.put<LoginController>(LoginController());
        super.initState();
      }
```

Once you know you have this instance in the widget tree, you just listen to its streams using GetX widget

```dart
GetX<LoginController>(
  builder: (controller)=>Text(controller.username.value)
)//this guy will repaint every time username changes
```

This is important because the instance of this widget will remain alive in the widget tree until either the app ends or the controller is explicitly deleted

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too sure how to initialize the controller in my widget tree - it throws a lot of errors when I do so. When I just use the GetX widget, it doesn't show the text for some reason.

Comment: @Neek666 sorry, I pasted a wrong code when talked about initializing. It's fixed now